# Qualys container image scanning in GitHub Actions

Tags: qualys

I cannot find a Qualys Container Image scan action on [GitHub Market Place](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=Qualys%20).

Are there steps I can follow to create a custom script to check container image build for vulnerabilities with Qualys?